# Why my background are so big in simulator xcode?

Tags: xcode

why are my picture background so big in simulator but not in the layout. ?!

i have try to change from iphone to ipad but my problem still there.

printscreen:

[IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/15y9r4g.png[/IMG]

Comment: Not all of us can access that image so we don't know what you are talking about. Please can you edit your question to use the image feature.

Comment: you can look at the pic now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 6 provide the facility to automatically adjust views. In order to disable this you must uncheck this. Select Your View Controller and disable Use auto layout.

[image]